# vba: insert a column in each file into a folder and subfolders

Tags: excel, vba, file

i need to modify all of the excel files stored into a folder (and subfolders).
The operations are:
open the file
find the right worksheet
insert a column and give it a specified name
modify the column at the right and change its name
copy the style from a column to the brand new
save the file
continue with the next file.

here you find my code:

```
Sub LoopFiles()
Dim Filename, Pathname As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Pathname = ("C:\scriptest\")
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*2021.xlsm")
Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
    InsertCol wb
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

and the second function is:

```
Sub InsertCol(wb As Workbook)
With wb
    Worksheets("colours").Activate
   Columns("E:E").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range("E2").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "RED"
            Range("F2").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "GREEN"
            Range("F2").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("E2").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
           Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
End With
End Sub
```

I saved the query into a file, but for some reason, excel applies the changes only in that file.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry, i posted right now: it wasn't formatted properly ;)

Comment: In your InsertCol-sub you are implicitly referencing the workbook in which the code runs. Add a **dot** in front of `worksheets("colours")`as well as in front of `columns("E:E")` and each `Range` --> then they are explicitly referencing `wb` (as you put `with wb` at the beginning.

Comment: @ike actually `Worksheets("colours").Activate` implicitly references _ActiveWorkbook_ which generally may or may not be the book containing the code.  In this case it's (probably) the workbook just opened

Comment: @chrisneilsen you are right - but nevertheless, it is pretty sure the reason why it fails

Comment: Hi to everyone! thanks for suggestions! The vba scripts now works, but only for the files in the same folder. I need to search in all subfolders and insert the column in all the files with the "2021.xlsm" at the end of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the `wb` to your sub, and start `With` block on it.  That's good.  But then you don't use it.  And all that Active/Select stuff is bad .

In particular note the`.` before `Columns` and `Range` .  That's what refers back to the `With` object

Here's an outline of what it should be

```vb
Sub InsertCol(wb As Workbook)
    With wb.Worksheets("colours")
        .Columns("E:E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "RED"
       ' etc
        Wb.Save
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @chrisneilsen. the macro works only with the files in the same folder.
How can I modify the macro to insert the column into the files in the subfolders?